# Allow woocommerce prices to accept text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am wondering, I have been stuck on this for ages and no amount of Google searching has helped. Basically, with Woocommerce, as most of you probably know, if you try to enter text into 'Regular Price' or 'Sale Price' it will not accept it.

Is there a way to allow it to?